# Index error when creating 3d list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 3d list but keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
grid = []
for row in range(10):
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(10):
        grid[row].append([])
        for height in range(10):
            grid[column][row].append([])
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kosay.jabre/Desktop/3dgrid.py", line 7, in <module>
    grid[column][row].append([])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't see my mistake, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example when `column` is equal to 1 (and `row` is still 0) on the last line

```
grid[column][row].append([])
```

there is no element in `grid` which can be obtained with `grid[1]` and this causes error.

We can change last line to

```
grid[row][column].append([])
```

For this task we can also use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like

```
grid = [[[[]
          for height in range(10)]
         for column in range(10)]
        for row in range(10)]
```

why not @rassar suggestion? because it will duplicate the same `list`s and  it is not what you want i suppose (more in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)):

```
>>>grid = [[[[]
          for height in range(10)]
         for column in range(10)]
        for row in range(10)]
>>>grid2 = [[[[]] * 10] * 10] * 10
>>>grid[0][0][0].append(1)
>>>grid2[0][0][0].append(1)
>>>grid
 [[[[1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]],
  [[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]],
  [[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]],
  [[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]],
  [[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]],
  [[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]],
  [[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]],
  [[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]],
  [[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]],
  [[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []],
   [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]]]
>>>grid2
[[[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]],
 [[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]],
 [[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]],
 [[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]],
 [[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]],
 [[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]],
 [[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]],
 [[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]],
 [[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]],
 [[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]],
  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]]]
```

finally you should take a look at [**NumPy**](http://www.numpy.org/) which is all about multidimensional arrays

Comment: While you _could_ use a nested list comprehension, in this case it is a much better option to simply use a regular for-loop. Your are not really gaining much by using them, and your only adding to the visual noise.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `grid[row][column]` instead of `grid[column][row]`.

Note that you can not do `[[[[]]*10]*10]*10` as it will create aliases and when one list is modified they all get modified.

Comment: -1 While your explanation for the OP's error is correct, your solution is wrong. Doing `grid = [[[[]]*10]*10]*10` will not create new list in `grid`. Rather, it will only create new _references_ to the same list objects in `grid`. Thus, you cannot set grid positions to unique values. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) for more information on the topic.

Comment: What @ChristianDean said. Try `grid = [[[[]]*4]*4]*4; grid[1][1][1].append(1); print(grid)`

Answer (score 1):

As rassar mentions, you got that indexing error because you reversed your indices. You should've had `grid[row][column]`instead of `grid[column][row]`.

Here's the standard way to make a regular "multidimensional" list in Python.

```
def show(g):
    for block in g:
        for row in block:
            print(row)
        print()
    print()

grid = []
for z in range(3):
    block = []
    for y in range(4):
        row = [0] * 5
        block.append(row)
    grid.append(block)

show(grid)

for z in range(3):
    for y in range(4):
        for x in range(5):
            n = 100 * z + 10 * y + x + 111
            grid[z][y][x] = n

show(grid)
```

**output**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


[111, 112, 113, 114, 115]
[121, 122, 123, 124, 125]
[131, 132, 133, 134, 135]
[141, 142, 143, 144, 145]

[211, 212, 213, 214, 215]
[221, 222, 223, 224, 225]
[231, 232, 233, 234, 235]
[241, 242, 243, 244, 245]

[311, 312, 313, 314, 315]
[321, 322, 323, 324, 325]
[331, 332, 333, 334, 335]
[341, 342, 343, 344, 345]
```

However, it's probably more common *not* to fully initialize a list like this. Rather, just create a base list and expand it as you need to. If you truly do need a proper multidimensional array, consider using Numpy.

---

BTW, it possible to condense those `for` loops into a nested list comprehension:

```
grid = [[[0] * 5 for y in range(4)] for z in range(3)]
```

It's certainly more compact than the previous code, and slightly faster, but a little less readable.

To improve readability we can spread it out over a few lines

```
grid = [
    [[0] * 5 for y in range(4)] 
        for z in range(3)
]
```

but it's still rather dense, and until you're very comfortable with Python I recommend using the traditional `for` loop method that I used earlier.

Comment: What are the advantages of using Numpy for multidimensional arrays? Can I store Python objects inside Numpy arrays?

Comment: @Kos One of the biggest advantages is speed. NumPy arrays are implemented in C and are much faster than normal Python arrays. A downside however, is that all data in the arrays must be homogeneous.

Comment: @Kos: yes, you can create `NumPy` arrays from `list`s/`tuple`s

Comment: @Kos Yes, you _can_ store Python objects in Numpy arrays, but they're designed to store native machine numeric types (eg various sizes of signed and unsigned integers and floating point numbers), on which Numpy can operate at the speed of compiled code. But before you get into Numpy it's a good idea to master the basics of core Python.